# Stop Hidden Text From Changing Size of Parent div

Tags: html, css, hover

I have a panel that displays a piece of text. I want to be able to mouse over the panel and have it display new text. 
The problem I'm having is that the hover text I want to display makes the panel bigger than I want it to be.

To put it simply the panel should look like a completely new panel when hovered over, i.e. a different colour with different text.

I found this example jsFiddle that someone posted, which is essentially what I want to achieve, but I'm not using an image underneath. 
http://jsfiddle.net/xsFmA/345/

Here is my example jsFiddle:

```css
.h2 {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.class-type-item {
 position: relative; 
 margin: 20px;
 text-align:center;
 padding:70px;
 background-color:black;
    color:grey;
}

.hover-text {
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
    position: relative;
 color:black;
}

.class-type-item:hover {
 background-color:#AD1515;
}

.class-type-item:hover p {
    opacity:1;
    float:left;
}

.class-type-item:hover h2 {
    opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="class-type-item" >
            <h2>Yoga Classes</h2>
            <p class="hover-text">description goes here </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can only seem to find examples using images. Any help or pointers would be a great help!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `height` and `width` of your container `class-type-item` and the two panels `h2` and `p` to same values. Let's say `height: 100px` and `width: 150px;`

```
.class-type-item,
h2,
p {
    height: 100px;
    width: 150px;
}
```

Then add `position: absolute` to the panels. As then position them on top of each other within the container. No need for `float: left`.

```
h2,
p {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer philipb3. That worked for me!

The only problem is, it's not very compatible with mobile devices. As it is a set size it doesn't scale well. This is probably worthy of a completely new question anyway, but maybe there's a way to do it using while using bootstraps span or col-md for only for example.

Answer (score 1):

The code that is changing the size of the div is this:

```
.class-type-item:hover p {
    float:left;
}
```

Remove the float:left on hover, and the div will stay the same size on hover.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set a height for the container div "class-type-item"?

Comment: Defining a width and height isn't very nice for different devices. I would like to keep it so that it resizes depending on the size of the screen.

I have tried it as I mentioned above and it works, but it's not the exact solution I'm looking for unfortunately